# Postfix: define a global concurrency_limit

Tags: postfix, connections, smtpd

I need to limit the simultaneous outgoing connections Postfix can make.

It is possible to limit the number of connection **per destination** with `transport_destination_concurrency_limit`, but not globally (or at least I didn't understand how).

For spam reasons my ISP is limiting the number of simultaneous outgong SMTP connections, so I'd like to shape this in Postfix to maximize delivery times.

Answer (score 2):

If you check `postconf  | grep default_destination_concurrency_limit` you can see how the various `--xxxxxx--_destination_concurrency_limit` are set.

The default values are:  smtp_destination_.., relay_destination.. etc points to `$default_destination_concurrency_limit`, and the value is set to **20**

If a value is set to a sepcific transport, like smtp, it will override the default value (obviously)

The next item to check/match is `postconf | grep destination_recipient_limit`

Depending on the value set for a specific transport, like smtp, it will cause the *meaning*  of the value set for `smtp_destination_concurrency_limit` as follows:

**Value = 1** smtp_concurrency_limit is referring to the same recipient.

**Value > 1** smtp_concurrency_limit is referring to the same domain.

Different recipients/domains are delivered in parallel, subject to the process limits specified in master.cf.

The default process limit is 100 (if not set explicitly) , so you have to limit the smtp max processes to "your value" = max concurrent accepted by your ISP

See also [postconf man page](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html)
and [master.cf](http://www.postfix.org/master.5.html)

Comment: Given that my problem is not related to the domain, I basically need to change the process limit. I ended up with the same solution from another thread, once I've the chance to test it I will accept the answer

Comment: the line to be changed is this, right? `smtp      unix  -       -       y       -       5       smtp`

Comment: In my servers, the last position is "smtpd" and not "smtp"
i.e. the process used to perform the smtp outgoing connection.

Maybe it is distro specific? mine is Centos

Comment: Edit: (my misstake in previous comment.I looked at the wrong config line)

Yes, this looks like the correct statement